# Copying data from textBox to cmd using startInfo.Arguments

Tags: c#, cmd

I need to write the serial number (text) from a textBox to cmd command using **startInfo.Arguments**.
The main point is, all searches I did here pointed to replace the text in the beggining or in the end of the arguments. 
But I need to insert the text from textBox to the middle of the argument, like this:

```
string input1 = textBox1.Text;
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.FileName = "CMD.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "/c adb -s "textBox1.Text" shell dumpsys battery";
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Definitely look into basic C# tutorials.. This is simple string concatenation/interpolation.

Comment: You concatenate strings with `+`. E.g. `"one" + "two"`.

Comment: Have you tried the normal string concatenation? `startInfo.Arguments = "/c adb -s " + textBox1.Text + " shell dumpsys battery";`

Comment: hi alejandro, I tried but no results. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by *"I tried but no results"*? What is the value of `startInfo.Arguments` after trying that answer?

Answer (score 0):

The content of the textbox has already been stored in the `input1` variable.

Now we have multiple options to do this in C#:

```
startInfo.Arguments = String.Format(@"/c adb -s ""{0}"" shell dumpsys battery", input1);
```

(in the @ string notation, double quotes are preserved in the resulting string by doubling them)

or with concatenation:

```
startInfo.Arguments = "/c adb -s \"" + input1 + "\" shell dumpsys battery";
```

(the backslash-escaped double quotes will preserve the double quote in the resulting string)

or, recently, we can use string interpolation:

```
startInfo.Arguments = $@"/c adb -s ""{input1}"" shell dumpsys battery";
```

Either way, consider to validate the value before you execute anything you obtained from a user, especially when it is started with administrative privileges.

Comment: hello, thank you! But I tried the commands but none had effect!

Comment: @ClaudeHitech What do you mean by *"none had effect"*? What is the value of `startInfo.Arguments` after trying one of these answers?

Comment: Hi Rufus, the content of argument is the serialnumber of the device: ce022111a3a6766e02. If I store this value in the argument field, after the -s, it works normally.

Comment: @Rufus thanks, done. @OP, ok so adb is the *android debug bridge*. maybe the quotes should not be part of the string then. let's remove them. on the other hand, you are redirecting the standard output. if there is a problem with the `Process.Start` part of your code, edit your question to include that.

Comment: Tried the commands aboce, but they did not work for any reason...even after removed the quotes!

Comment: please show the code after. how are you using the `startInfo` after constructing it? `Process.Start` would follow.